# Update and Display a Coordinate Axis being Rotating and Translated in Real Time in Matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib, rotation, quaternions, coordinate-systems, matplotlib-animation

I'm currently trying to recreate this: [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ijArKE8vKU&ab_channel=SebMadgwickResearch), and I could not find how to recreate the 3D visualization step, where coordinate axis are translated and rotated around, in matplotlib. Does anyone know how to do in matplotlib's animation, updating the results in real time?

Comment: You mean the graph that describe climbing a spiral stairs ?

Comment: Here an example rotate axis view http://blog.mahler83.net/2019/10/rotating-3d-t-sne-animated-gif-scatterplot-with-matplotlib/   and https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-change-angle-of-3d-plot-in-python/amp/